# Excel split data into first columns and then rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking for functionality with Excel that can parse a specific text with two delimiters into first columns and then rows.

For example, suppose that I have the text with specific format: `"1,2,3;4,5,6"`. I want it to be as below in Excel:

[image]

So it should separate first based on semicolon (into rows), and then based on the colon (into columns). To do this, I'm trying to use a combination of `SPLIT` and `transpose` functions of Excel. It works fine for the first stage, where with formula: `transpose(SPLIT("1,2,3;4,5,6", ";"))`, I obtain the following:

[image]

But when I'm then trying to split the resulting cells by colon with formula: `SPLIT(transpose(SPLIT("1,2,3;4,5,6", ";")), ",")`, it just parses the first row, and skips the second as bellow:

[image]

Anyone has suggestion to cope with this?

Comment: SPLIT is not a standard Excel function, where did you get it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **Excel365**, pick a cell and enter:

```
={1,2,3;4,5,6}
```

which will spill into:

[image]

If you are not using **Excel365**, you would need to use an array formula.

Comment: Works perfectly fine! Thanks!

Comment: @inverted_index You are quite welcome.